# What is the difference between Linux and Unix?

Tags: linux, unix

Can some one please explain the major difference between Linux and Unix?

Comment: Google is a better resource for this kind of question than SO.

Comment: Technical Reference:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-unix-difflinux.html

Comment: Well, I believe that user can ask such questions here so that we have single largest information repository that is trustworthy !!

Answer (score 10):

Unix was written at Bell Labs AT&T back in the 70s.

Linux is a port of Unix for PCs written by Linus Torvalds and released to open source in 1991.

Answer (score 2):

Check this: http://www.unixguide.net/linux/lnag/lnag1.5.shtml
Linux is basically an unix-like Kernel where Unix is itself a self-established Kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Unix is propriety kernel designed for a more select audience (ie servers). It is mostly propriety code.

Linux is is designed for a general purpose audience (ie. desktops). It is open source. Linux was based on Unix.